# Recommendations for free SQL CBT's

Tags: sql

Are there any good sites, free preferably, that offer introductory to intermediate learning for SQL skills, either generic SQL, or MSSQL? If seen some good ones on Microsoft's site, www.asp.net, but they head down the development path pretty quickly.

For paid solutions, is CBTNuggets worth the money?

Answer (score 1):

Head down to [SQLServerCentral.com](http://www.sqlservercentral.com) its the place to be for improving your SQL skills!

You have to signup to view the articles but its worth it!